# How can I create new TeamCity users through the API?

Tags: api, teamcity

I want to create TeamCity users with various roles through the API. As long as I provide no role, I know how to do it, like so:

```bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:8111/app/rest/users \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"username":"user", "password":"password"}' \
  -u :<super-user-token>
```

Now, my issue is that e.g. I want to create an administrator. I tried this:

```bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:8111/app/rest/users \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"username":"user", "password":"password", "roles": {"role": [{"roleId": "PROJECT_ADMIN"}]}}' \
  -u :<super-user-token>
```

The roleId is a value that comes from the `roles-config.xml` file in folder `<TeamCity Data Directory>/config`, should be fine. I get the following error:

```
Responding with error, status code: 400 (Bad Request).
Details: jetbrains.buildServer.server.rest.errors.PartialUpdateError: Partial error updating user 'zadigus' {id=3}, nested errors: jetbrains.buildServer.server.rest.errors.PartialUpdat
eError: Partial error updating roles for user 'zadigus' {id=3}, nested errors: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'scopeData' of jetbrains/buildServer/
server/rest/model/user/RoleAssignment.getScope must not be null
There was an error processing the request, but the data could be updated partially. Please ensure consistent data state.
```

because I provide no scope. I was not able to find any information about what values I can feed the `scope` field with. Where are they documented?

I am using TeamCity version 2022.04.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. In order to get the possible values for the `scope` field, just run

```bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:8111/app/rest/users \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"username":"user", "password":"password", "roles": {"role": [{"roleId": "PROJECT_ADMIN", "scope": "invalid-value"}]}}' \
  -u :<super-user-token>
```

In the reply to this request, we get the information that possible values are either `g` or `p:<projectId>`.